# how to self join table with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which stores facebook handles along side the date they were gathered.

I want to create a query which selects the facebook handles from the database in date order on the same line.

so something like this

```
facebookHandle    date          facebookhandle  date
asos              2015-03-06    dreams          2015-03-03
argos             2015-03-06    test            2015-03-03
```

I was looking at self join examples but I couldnt figure it out.

Original database

```
id        facebookHandle   date
=======    =======        ========
1           asos          2015-03-06
2           argos         2015-03-06
3           tesco         2015-03-06
4           test          2015-03-03
5           loyd          2015-03-03
6           dreams        2015-03-03
7           halfords      2015-03-03
```

Comment: Do you only have two dates?  Normally, this type of data manipulation -- although possible in SQL -- is best done in the application.

Comment: No there will be quite a few dates. Do you think it's best to use arrays and deal with it from their?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat() function which will give the comma separated value like this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(facebookHandle) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY date
```

By This you will get facebookHandle in a row of date.